Bounded Random Walks vs Non-Bounded Random Walks
Recently I posted this question here on the probability distribution of two Random Walks (1 dimensional and on the integer line) meeting each other: When and Where will 2 Random Walks Meet for the First Time?. Here are the general forms of these 2 Random Walks $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ ($x_0$ and $y_0$ are the initial positions of both Random Walks ):
$$
X(t) = 
\begin{cases} 
x_0 & \text{if } t = 0 \\
X(t-1) + S_x(t) & \text{if } t > 0 
\end{cases}
$$
$$
Y(t) = 
\begin{cases} 
y_0 & \text{if } t = 0 \\
Y(t-1) + S_y(t) & \text{if } t > 0 
\end{cases}
$$
$$
S_x(t) = 
\begin{cases} 
+1 & \text{with probability } p= p_1 \\
-1 & \text{with probability } p= 1- p_1
\end{cases}
$$
$$
S_y(t) = 
\begin{cases} 
+1 & \text{with probability } p= p_2 \\
-1 & \text{with probability } p= 1- p_2
\end{cases}
$$
I am interested in knowing the probability distribution functions of when and where they will meet for the first time (joint and marginals)
After having posted this question, I am now thinking that there is a possibility that the answer to this question might be $0$ probability and an infinite number of steps.
To better understand this, I tried to make a flow chart of different types of problems (e.g. continuous vs integer, constrained vs unconstrained, exact intersection vs intersection within a certain range) involving the intersection of Random Walks:

To elaborate on these definitions:

Unconstrained Integer Domain:  $x(t), y(t) \in \mathbb{Z}$
Constrained Integer Domain: $a < X(t), Y(t) < b$, $x(t), y(t) \in \mathbb{Z}$
Unconstrained Continuous Domain: $x(t), y(t) \in \mathbb{R}$
Constrained Continuous Domain: $a < X(t), Y(t) < b$, $x(t), y(t) \in \mathbb{R}$
Exact Meeting: $x(t) = y(t)$
Meeting within Range: $| x(t) - y(t)| \leq c$

All together, this would result in 8 scenarios:

Scenario 1: Integer, Constrained, Exact Meeting
Scenario 2: Integer, Constrained, Within Range
Scenario 3: Integer, Unconstrained, Exact Meeting
Scenario 4: Integer, Unconstrained, Within Range
Scenario 5: Continuous, Constrained, Exact Meeting
Scenario 6: Continuous, Constrained, Within Range
Scenario 7: Continuous, Unconstrained, Exact Meeting
Scenario 8: Continuous, Unconstrained, Within Range

Now, for each of these scenarios, I am trying to write the probability distribution functions of when and where they will meet for the first time (joint and marginals). Furthermore, I am not sure which of these scenarios will have 0 probabilities of meeting and infinite meeting time.
For example, I tried writing the generic distributions for Scenario 1 (Integer, Constrained, Exact Meeting):
$$x_0, y_0, X(t), Y(t) \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad a \leq x_0, y_0, X(t), Y(t) \leq b$$
$$P(T \geq t | p_1, p_2, x_0, y_0, X(t-1), Y(t-1)) ~\sim ???$$
$$P(X(t) = Y(t) = x | T \geq t, p_1, p_2, x_0, y_0, X(t-1), Y(t-1)) ~\sim ???$$
$$P(T \geq t, X(t) = Y(t) = x | p_1, p_2, x_0, y_0, X(t-1), Y(t-1)) ~\sim ???$$
I tried writing it for Scenario 2:
Let $T$ be the time that the absolute distance between both random walks is less than equal to 5 for the first time,
$$ x_0, y_0, X(t), Y(t) \in \mathbb{Z} \quad \forall t $$
$$
A(t) = 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } |X(t) - Y(t)| \leq c \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
$$ P(A(t) = 1 | A(t-1) = a(t-1), p_1, p_2, X(t-1), Y(t-1)) ~\sim ??? $$
$$ P(T \geq t | x_0, y_0, p_1, p_2, X(t-1), Y(t-1)) ~\sim ??? $$
$$ P(X(t) = x | A(t) = 1, p_1, p_2, X(t-1), Y(t-1)) ~\sim ??? $$
$$ P(Y(t) = y | A(t) = 1, p_1, p_2, X(t-1), Y(t-1)) ~\sim ??? $$
$$ P(A(t) = 1, X(t) = x, Y(t) = y | p_1, p_2, X(t-1), Y(t-1)) ~\sim ??? $$
I am really starting to get confused on how to even correctly write the joint and marginal conditional probability distributions for these problems, let alone know how to derive an expression for them.
Can someone please help me understand which of these scenarios will have non-zero probabilities of intersection and how to derive the probability distributions?
Note: In case anyone is interested, here is the computer code (R programming language) used for creating this flow chart:
root <- Node$new("Root")
integerNode <- root$AddChild("Integer")
continuousNode <- root$AddChild("Continuous")

=for (i in 1:2) {
    child <- integerNode$AddChild(ifelse(i %% 2 == 0, "Unconstrained", "Constrained"))
    child$AddChild("Exact Meeting")
    child$AddChild("Within Range")
}

for (i in 1:2) {
    child <- continuousNode$AddChild(ifelse(i %% 2 == 0, "Unconstrained", "Constrained"))
    child$AddChild("Exact Meeting")
    child$AddChild("Within Range")
}

graph <- ToDiagrammeRGraph(root)


DiagrammeR::render_graph(graph)

